# Querying the $avg day of week (mon avg, tue avg, wed avg) $sum in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to count records in a collection in mongodb which might be structured like this:

```
[{
Content: "some content",
TimeStamp: "some date"
}
,
{
Content: "some content",
TimeStamp: "some date"
}]
```

Now I would like to count records daily(per week), but I do not want the total count of records, I need the AVERAGE of the total count of records daily.

Here I have a query to get the total dayOfWeek records:

```
[
{
    "$unwind": "$Items"
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "day": {
                "$dayOfWeek": "$Items.TimeStamp"
            }
        },
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {
        "count": -1
    }
}
```

]

This returns:

> {{ "_id" : { "day" : 2 }, "count" : 604 }} {{ "_id" : { "day" : 6 },
> "count" : 569 }} {{ "_id" : { "day" : 4 }, "count" : 503 }}    {{ "_id"
> : { "day" : 1 }, "count" : 425 }} {{ "_id" : { "day" : 3 }, "count" :
> 417 }}     {{ "_id" : { "day" : 5 }, "count" : 401 }}  {{ "_id" : { "day"
> : 7 }, "count" : 340 }}

This is the total count for records on monday, tuesday, wednesday etc

How would I get the AVERAGE on Monday, average on Tuesday?

---

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

Using Monday as an example

Week 1 Monday: 5

Week 2 Monday: 9

Week 3 Monday: 41

Week 4 Monday: 35

Week 5 Monday: 47

### Monday Average: 27.4 (THIS IS THE VALUE THAT IS NEEDED)
Monday Total: 137 (THIS IS WHAT CURRENT QUERY RETURNS)

Obviously I could count all the Mondays and just divide the Total value by number of Mondays counted in the dataset. Which I will need to do in C# (I am using mongodb c# driver) but I would ideally like to perform the whole operation in a MondayDB operation.

Comment: Hi, could you add an example desired output?

Comment: @HanielBaez Hi! I added output to the end. If you could have a look and send me in the right direction, that would be good. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, right now is no clear how are you expecting the average of day. Would you add an example document?